# internal server error (500) in simple cgi script

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I am trying to run a simple cgi script after configuring my server.

My script looks like this:

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>CGI</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "hello cgi"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

When I go to my scripts url `http://127.0.0.1/~flybywire/cgi-bin/main.py` I get:

**Internal Server Error**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

And in `error.log` I get the following:

`[error] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/home/flybywire/www/cgi-bin/main.py' failed
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: main.py`

**Other info:** `Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.4.6 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might need a `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of your script to tell Apache to use Python to execute it.  At least, I did that and it worked for me :-) .

Comment: I think add  `#!/usr/bin/python` to all cgi script is scary. How to set it by apache SetEnv PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 13):

Also, save the file (if this is a Linux server) with Unix line endings. You did make it executable using `chmod +x` didn't you?

You can use `#!/usr/bin/env python` to cover the current running Python version if you're running in various environments (hence the `env` part).

Comment: When I tried it without `chmod +x` there was a different error: `(13)Permission denied: exec of '/home/flybywire/www/cgi-bin/main.py' failed`.

Comment: That's simply because chmod +x makes the file permissions executable - making the file executable is a prerequisite, really.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Apache has trouble executing it. Typically for a unix script you also need to specify the interpreter at the top of the script.

Try adding this to the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

on the top of the script works fine. I put it on top, but Netbeans was putting extra code (import commands) by itself on the top of the page which drove me crazy :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that new python version needs parentheses ( ).

So your:

```
print "<body>"
```

Now should to be:

```
print ("<body>")
```

Comment: They are using Python2 not Python3.

Answer (score 0):

remove the 2nd line in your program (print)
I tried it on my apache server (mac os x) it works fine.
don't forget to chmod 755 and reboot with sudo apachectl restart 
This is for python 2.7

```
print "Content-type: text/html"
print "<html><head><title>CGI</title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "hello cgi"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not know where to find python on your PC to execute that file.
Try to add #!C:/python as 1st line on your .py file (or wherever location Python is installed on your PC).

Answer (score 0):

If it's python 3, you may add `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of the program instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`.
*(As I'm French, I think my English is not totally correct)*