# CGI Script Internal Server Error Windows

Tags: python, cgi

I am new to CGI Scripting. I have installed Wamp Server on Windows and Installed Python at Path D:\Installation\Python33.

I have written CGI Script (test.cgi) as:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print "<html><head><title>Books</title></head>"
print "<body><h1>Books</h1>These are the books</body></html>"
```

I kept it under C:\wamp\www\ direcotry.
When I run it from browser it gives me error "Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I checked apache_error.log shows :

```
[Sun May 18 12:30:13 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : couldn't create child process: 720003: test.cgi
[Sun May 18 12:30:13 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 3)The system cannot find the path specified.  : couldn't spawn child process: C:/wamp/www/test.cgi
```

I think Python Path needs to be set here.

I found similar question here :

[internal server error (500) in simple cgi script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464728/internal-server-error-500-in-simple-cgi-script)

but could not find how to set python path on windows. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

I modified first line to setup python path and then used sys module to write the output as :

```
#!d:/Installations/Python33/python.exe

import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("<html><head><title>Books</title></head>")
sys.stdout.write("<body><h1>Books</h1>These are the books</body></html>")
```

and It worked !!!

Comment: it works but why not simple print("hello world") not working here

Answer (score 0):

place your script in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\cgi-bin` 
(if you don't have cgi-bin folder then create one)

and then enable cgi in your `"httpd.conf"`

i.e. find `<DIRECTORY />` and replace it with this(in your `httpd.conf` file)

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

for windows(on localhost)

```
#!D:\Installation\Python33
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><head><title>Books</title></head>")
print("<body><h1>Books</h1>These are the books</body></html>")
```

and call your script like this

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/yourfilename
```

Comment: @vijay you are using python33. so print function is as follow print("your content") not like print "your content"

Answer (score 0):

use this code in test.py

```
#!python

print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
print ("python test ok\r\n<br/>")
#print (help)
help (os.chmod())
```

and put D:\Installation\Python33 in path variable

restart apache

note: Wamp Server have to install in D drive.

I hope this will work